# $a^p \equiv b^p \pmod p \Rightarrow a^p \equiv b^p \pmod {p^2}$

Tags: number-theory

I am looking at the following exercise and I got stuck..

If $p$ is prime, $p \nmid a$, $p \nmid b$, prove that $$a^p \equiv b^p \pmod p \Rightarrow a^p \equiv b^p \pmod {p^2}$$

Could you give me some hint what I could do??

Comment: By Fermat's Little Theorem, $a\equiv b \mod p$. Does that help?

Comment: @Nishant Is it as followed:

$$a^p=(b+kp)^p=b^p+p^2kb^{p-1}+\frac{1}{2}(p-1)p^3b^{p-2}k^2+ \dots + bk^{p-1}p^p$$

$$p^2 \mid p^2kb^{p-1}+\frac{1}{2}(p-1)p^3b^{p-2}k^2+ \dots + bk^{p-1}p^p \Rightarrow p^2 \mid a^p-b^p$$
??

Answer (score 9):

By Fermat's little theorem $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$, same for $b$. Thus $a \equiv b \pmod{p}$. This means $a=b+pk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now raise both sides to $p^{\text{th}}$ power and apply binomial theorem.

Comment: Applying the binomial theorem, we get:
$$a^p=(b+kp)^p=\sum_{m=0}^p \binom{p}{m}(kp)^m b^{p-m}=\binom{p}{0}b^p+\binom{p}{1}(kp)b^{p-1}+ \dots+ \binom{p}{p}(kp)^p= \\ b^p+kp^2b^{p-1}+ \dots + (kp)^p$$

How does this help?

Comment: try showing that all the coefficients except the first one are divisible by $p^2$ (and hence they will be $0 \pmod{p^2}$

Comment: So, is it as followed:

$$a^p=(b+kp)^p=b^p+p^2 k b^{p-1}+\frac{1}{2}(p-1) p^3 b^{p-2}k^2+ \dots +b k^{p-1} p^p$$

$$p^2 \mid p^2 k b^{p-1}+\frac{1}{2}(p-1) p^3 b^{p-2}k^2+ \dots +b k^{p-1} p^p \Rightarrow p^2 \mid a^p-b^p$$

?? Or have I understood it wrong??